# How to make ImageSpan align by baseline

Tags: android

**Question**: Why is `ImageSpan` `ALIGN_BASELINE` not aligning accurately to baseline and how to fix this alignment issue?

In my activity, i create a `SpannableString` and replace part of the string with `ImageSpan`. `ImageSpan` uses a 24x24 pixel pure black png image and is set to `ALIGN_BASELINE`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello world!");

        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.box);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        ss.setSpan(imageSpan, 2, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        myTextView.setText(ss);
    }
}
```

I have a two views in my layout: a `TextView` and a `View` to show the baseline

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff9800"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/myTextView"
        android:background="#de4caf50"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, the line is correctly align to to `TextView`'s baseline but the `ImageSpan` is slightly lower than the baseline.

[image]

Comment: have you tried with ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is just, well, wrong. The drawable's vertical placement is off since [`ALIGN_BASELINE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.html#ALIGN_BASELINE) is defined as follows:

> A constant indicating that the bottom of this span should be aligned with the baseline of the surrounding text.

That is clearly not happening. See the end of this post for what is going wrong. I suggest the following for a fix:

```
// Override draw() to place the drawable correctly when ALIGN_BASELINE.
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE) {
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start,
                     int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom,
                     @NonNull Paint paint) {
        if (mVerticalAlignment != ALIGN_BASELINE) {
            super.draw(canvas, text, start, end, x, top, y, bottom, paint);
            return;
        }
        Drawable b = getDrawable();
        canvas.save();
        // If we set transY = 0, then the drawable will be drawn at the top of the text.
        // y is the the distance from the baseline to the top of the text, so
        // transY = y will draw the top of the drawable on the baseline. We want the             // bottom of the drawable on the baseline, so we subtract the height
        // of the drawable.
        int transY = y - b.getBounds().bottom;
        canvas.translate(x, transY);
        b.draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }
};
```

This code produces the following image which, I think, is correct.

[image]

---

**Why is the box not drawn on the baseline?**

Here is the source that draws the box from [DynamicDrawableSpan#draw()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan.java#136):

```
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text,
        @IntRange(from = 0) int start, @IntRange(from = 0) int end, float x,
        int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
    Drawable b = getCachedDrawable();
    canvas.save();
    int transY = bottom - b.getBounds().bottom;
    if (mVerticalAlignment == ALIGN_BASELINE) {
        transY -= paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
    }
    canvas.translate(x, transY);
    b.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

And the documentation for [DynamicDrawableSpan#draw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/DynamicDrawableSpan#draw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint)). The only argument to `draw()` that interests us is `bottom`:

> bottom int: Bottom of the line.

For the solution code and the emulator used, `transY` is calculated by `DynamicDrawableSpan` as 94, i.e., the box will be drawn 94 pixels from the top. `top` is 178 while the baseline is defined as zero, so 178 - 94 = 84 pixels which is the height of the box or `b.getBounds().bottom`. This checks out.

In `DynamicDrawableSpan#draw()` in the same emulator, bottom = 224 while the drawable's height is still 84 as shown above. Why is bottom 224? This is the line height of the font.

`transY` is now calculated as 224 - 84 = 140 pixels. This will place the bottom of the box at the bottom of the line but below the baseline.

One more adjustment is made:

```
transY -= paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
```

On the test,  `paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent` is 41, so `transY` now becomes 99. Since 94 is the right answer, 99 places the box five pixels too low and this is what you see.

See [Android 101: Typography](https://proandroiddev.com/android-and-typography-101-5f06722dd611) for  description of Android font metrics.

Comment: This is a nice answer, sir!

Comment: Thank you, @azizbekian!

Comment: This looks promising. Let me verify this answer over the next day or two before i accept your answer.

Comment: @Cheticamp so if i understand your explanation correctly, this is a bug with `DynamicDrawableSpan`? It seems like `DynamicDrawableSpan#draw` will work correctly for `ALIGN_BOTTOM` but will be wrong for `ALIGN_BASELINE` because whoever wrote this method thinks the distance from `bottom` to `descent` is the same as from `bottom` to `baseline`?

Comment: @Weizhi Bug, I would say. I just took a quick look at the issue tracker and found [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36934789) which appears to address the same issue. I don't know about "works incorrectly on last line only", but you may want to look into that if your text is more than one line.

Comment: @Weizhi Just did quick test: The `DynamicDrawableSpan` code seems to work on all lines _except_ the last line in  a multi-line `TextView`. The code I posted seems to work regardless of the line involved.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing drawable's xml, I'd say this line is the fault

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

And here's why:

Drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() returns **-1**, same goes for getIntrinsicWidth().

Which means you're calling setBounds() with following arguments:

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, -1, -1);

/**
 * Specify a bounding rectangle for the Drawable. This is where the drawable
 * will draw when its draw() method is called.
 */
public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
... // implementation
}
```

**edit:**

```
package android.graphics.drawable;

public abstract class Drawable {

...


/**
     * Returns the drawable's intrinsic height.
     * <p>
     * Intrinsic height is the height at which the drawable would like to be
     * laid out, including any inherent padding. If the drawable has no
     * intrinsic height, such as a solid color, this method returns -1.
     *
     * @return the intrinsic height, or -1 if no intrinsic height
     */
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no drawable xml. The black drawable is a 24x24 png image as mentioned in the question.